# Help adding checkbox to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I am a novice to google app scripts. However I need to copy selected rows (with a checkbox) to a second sheet. I am using this code below. However it copies the entire source sheet. I only need rows that I select to be copied.
Can someone please show me how to add a "checkbox" within the script so only the rows I checked are copied. Thanks

Code:

```
function copyRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getSheetByName("data 1");
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var srg=ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow()+1,ssh.getLastColumn());//assume 1 header row
  var svs=srg.getValues();
  var trg=tsh.getRange(2,1,tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);//assume 1 header row
  var tvs=trg.getValues().map(function(r){return new Date(r[0]).valueOf();});
  svs.forEach(function(r,i){
//if it is not in the target then append it to the target
    if(tvs.indexOf(new Date(r[0]).valueOf())==-1) {
      tsh.appendRow(r);
    }
  });
}
```

Note: my header does not contain a date column as mentioned below. However I will ask questions on that later.

Comment: Related: [Google Sheet - copy row if checkbox is active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68036067/1330560) StackOverflow

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). You are saying that the date processing you show in the code is of no consequence in the context of this question. Please remove superfluous lines in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this:

```
function appendCheckedRows() {
  const checkboxColumn = 3; // column C
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const data = ss.getRange('data 1!A2:Z')
    .getValues()
    .filter(row => row[checkboxColumn - 1] === true);
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  data.forEach(row => targetSheet.appendRow(row));
}
```